# Segmentation fault in production environment, Ruby 2.7.2 and Postgresql 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

versions i am using

```
Ruby 2.7.2
Rails 6.1.7.6
pg 1.5.4
postgresql 14
```

my database.yml file

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: host
  database: dbname
  username: postgres
  password: "##abc"
  port: 5432
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  gssencmode: disable
```

when i run
`export RAILS_ENV=production`
`rails c`

I'm greeted with this error

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:690: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007fc4b57f3140
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 544352) [x86_64-linux]
```

```
 -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0084 p:---- s:0480 e:000479 CFUNC  :connect_poll
c:0083 p:0551 s:0476 e:000475 METHOD /home/ubuntu/path/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:690
c:0082 p:0356 s:0463 e:000462 METHOD /home/ubuntu/path/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:824
c:0081 p:0007 s:0452 e:000451 METHOD /home/ubuntu/path/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:759
c:0080 p:0019 s:0446 e:000445 METHOD /home/ubuntu/path/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg.rb:63

c:0002 p:0031 s:0006 e:000005 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:001ba0 (none) [FINISH]
```

how can i resolve this segmentation fault?
this is the issue with production only, in development it was working fine, i tried to reinstall the pg gem multiple times, but no luck.

when i did,  `pg_lsclusters`
it's online,
`14  main    5432 online postgres`

Comment: 1) If it works in dev and not prod, what are the differences between dev and prod? 2) Try the latest Ruby 2.7 which is [2.7.8](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/). The problem might just go away. It's also the *last* Ruby 2. 3) What operating system are you on?

Comment: hi, i am using ubuntu

Comment: Try using the URL instead in your database.yml file:
format should look like this: postgres://db_user:db_pass@localhost/db_name

Comment: The `gssencmode` is the only thing that jumps out at me as something unusual, do you have that in dev? Have you tried prod without it? (I realize your setting is disabling it, just a shot in the dark)